# how to publish updates of application on multiple server IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

The same question was asked in 2012 regarding web application update on multiple servers [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963865/how-to-make-the-files-in-multiple-server-synchronous-when-update-my-application). I do have a similar situation but here in my case my web.config is changed for each server so it's not like load balancing stuff. So I'm trying to find other than web deploy is there any faster approach available to deploy updates of MVC application on multiple servers without touching web.config files. Currently, we are doing it manually. Any hint or link will be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For now, the most convenient way to deploy an application to multiple IIS is to use MSDeploy.

If you do not want to use MSDeploy and do not need to touch web.config, as far as I know, you can use visual studio to deploy the application to a folder, copy the folder to each IIS server, manually add sites or write powershell files, Execute this file on each server.

Comment: got other task on priority, so its on hold now